# Кривая верстка страницы

Tags: html, css, html5

Народ, задача простая, но я никак не могу понять что исправить, давно не занимался html.
Есть сайт: http://static.directcrm.ru/webpage/polls/mindbox/test.html

Полетел блок верстки, как выровнять его под общий стиль?

Comment: Добавить `body { display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; align-items: center; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первые блоки (точнее, таблицы) находятся внутри еще одной таблицы-обертки (с классом main-table), которая формирует ширину центральной колонки.